# Is it normal that u-substitution leaves behind a constant besides C?

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

Hello in the following problem $\int{(x^2+2)(x^3+6x+1)^5}$, using u-substitution we get the following: $\frac{(x^3+6x+1)^6}{18} + C$, but when we simplify this in the constant end we get $1/18$ alongside $C$, however if we do the integral of the question but fully simplified($x^{17}+.....+2$), we do not get the $1/18$, in fact we don't get any constant. Why are these integrals different? Is there some limitations of u-sub I should know about?

Comment: Two integrals are equivalent if they differ by a constant.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Wow, I didn't know that? But that's so strange, like why?

Comment: An integral of a function $f(x)$ is *any* function whose derivative is $f(x)$. So two functions can be integrals of $f(x)$ even though they differ in their constant terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in fact we don't get any constant.

How is that? You should still have the **constant of integration** and in fact because of this, the difference you think is there, actually isn't...

> Why are these integrals different?

When we write
$$\int \left( x+1 \right) \,\mbox{d}x = \color{green}{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}+\color{blue}{C} \quad\quad \left(C \in \mathbb{R}\right)$$
the " $+C$ " makes sure we didn't write ***an** antiderivative* of $x+1$, but *(**all**) the antiderivatives*.

Now compare with using a (simple) $u$-substitution ($u=x+1$) for the same problem:
$$\int \left( x+1 \right) \,\mbox{d}x =\int u \,\mbox{d}u = \frac{u^2}{2}+C= \frac{\left( x+1 \right)^2}{2}+C= \color{green}{\frac{x^2}{2}+x}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}+C}  \quad\quad \left(C \in \mathbb{R}\right)$$

It may not look the same, but we get the exact same (set of) antiderivatives.

To get one specific antiderivative, the values of the "blue $C$" and "red $C$" will differ (by $1/2$).

Comment: Ooops by any constant i was disregarding C. But yes I do see your point, so any constant in the integral is basically saying to 'mix me with C'?

Comment: You could say that: if "C" can be any real number, then you're "catching" exactly the same with "1/2+C" or "D+C" where D is any other constant, for that matter. For this reason, constant terms are often "merged" with the constant of integration (technically, you should rename the constant then because as in my example, the red C wouldn't be the same as the blue C).

Answer (score 1):

The answers in both the cases are same. As you can always club the constant of integration with the constant value.
$\frac{1}{18} + C$ can be called a new constant $C_1$.